# ASP.NET MVC Global Filter gives redirect loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, action-filter, custom-action-filter

I'm trying to implement force redirect user to set password when the password is not set.

Initially the user will login using an initial password given to user. (The `PasswordHash` value is null. I'm using another value `initialPassword`).

So when the `PasswordHash` is still null, the user is redirected to `SetPassword` page.

This is the global filter I've written:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new CheckCandidatePasswordSetFilterAttribute());
    }
}

public class CheckCandidatePasswordSetFilterAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var principal = (ClaimsPrincipal)filterContext.HttpContext.User;

        if (principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated && principal.IsInRole(RoleNames.CandidateRole) &&
            !IsRouteSetToSetPassword(filterContext.RouteData.Values) && !IsRouteIsLogout(filterContext.RouteData.Values))
        {
            bool hasPassword = principal.HasClaim(CustomClaimTypes.CandidateHasPassword, true.ToString());
            if (!hasPassword)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new
                {
                    area = string.Empty,
                    controller = "Manage",
                    action = "SetPassword"
                }));
            }
            return;
        }
        
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    private bool IsRouteIsLogout(RouteValueDictionary routeData)
    {
        routeData.TryGetValue("area", out object area);
        if (area != null && !area.ToString().Equals(string.Empty))
            return false;

        if (!routeData.TryGetValue("controller", out object controller))
            return false;
        if (!routeData.TryGetValue("action", out object action))
            return false;

        return controller.ToString().Equals("Account", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && action.ToString().Equals("LogOff", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    private static bool IsRouteSetToSetPassword(RouteValueDictionary routeData)
    {
        routeData.TryGetValue("area", out object area);
        if (area != null && !area.ToString().Equals(string.Empty))
            return false;
    
        if (!routeData.TryGetValue("controller", out object controller))
            return false;
        if (!routeData.TryGetValue("action", out object action))
            return false;

        return controller.ToString().Equals("Manage", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && action.ToString().Equals("SetPassword", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

The problem is it gives a redirect loop.

[Here's a screenshot from browser network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brIZZ.png)

I'm still new to MVC and still puzzled with this.

The route configuration:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "ERecruitment.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Won't your action filter be executed for the `/Manage/Setpassword` route as well ?

Comment: @Shyju The `IsRouteSetToSetPassword` method checks that

Comment: Put a breakpoint and verify that.

Answer (score 0):

My bad.
It's a problem in the other place that causes this redirect loop

```
public ActionResult SetPassword()
    {
        var principal = (ClaimsPrincipal)User;
        if(principal.IsInRole(RoleNames.CandidateRole) 
              //the code below is the problem
             && principal.FindFirst(CustomClaimTypes.CandidateHasPassword).Equals(false.ToString()))
            return View();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

I just need to change the code to

```
if(principal.IsInRole(RoleNames.CandidateRole) && principal.HasClaim(CustomClaimTypes.CandidateHasPassword, false.ToString()))
```